# How can I import Class Library and it's dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard, class-library

I've created a Class Library and it has 2 NuGet dependencies. When I build the library, the .dll is generated and I can successfully reference it on other project using the "Add Reference" option on Visual Studio.

However, the NuGet dependencies that the Class Library has, I have to manually add them to the other project using the NuGet Package Manager.

There is any way to import the Class Library and make the other project automatically solve all the NuGet Dependencies that the library has?

Comment: is there a reason you reference the dll instead of referencing the project directly? and at least with VS enterprise you can bundle dll's

Comment: @PatrickBeynio I have to add this library to a Xamarin project later, I don't know if I can refer the project on a Xamarin project

Comment: You could make your library a nuget package itself including a nuspec with the required dependencies. See [https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/guides/create-packages-for-xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/guides/create-packages-for-xamarin) for instructions.

Comment: As Yosh said, we can Create and publish a NuGet package that including required dependencies.Please look at [Create and publish a NuGet package using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli).

Comment: What kind of class library project did you create? https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff The .NET Core/.NET Standard types can directly generate NuGet packages for you which links to all dependencies. Then all your NuGet package consumers can get dependencies easily.